# Physical Naming Strategy is ignored in SQLDelete annotation

Tags: hibernate, sql-delete

My phisical naming strategy mapped in persistance.xml works great except whaen trying to call em.remove on entity with SQLDelete annotation (trying to soft delete). Anyone had any similar problems?

my relevant persistance.xml

```
<properties>
        <property name="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy" value="common.hibernate.strategy.PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
```

Annotation:

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE MasGraphic MASG SET MASG .deleted = true WHERE MASG.id = ? and MASG.updated = ?")
```

And error is:

```
    Table "UPDATE MASGRAPHIC MASG SET MASG.deleted = true WHERE MASG.id = ? and MASG.updated = ? [42102-193]
[ERROR   ] HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement]
```

Edit: adding caused by part of exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "MASGRAPHIC" not found; SQL statement:
UPDATE MASGRAPHIC MASG SET MASG.deleted = true WHERE MASG.id = ? and MASG.updated = ? [42102-193]
```

My custom PhysicalNamingStrategyImpl configures that table is called MAS_GRAPHIC and not MASGRAPHIC.

P.S. I don't know any other relevant information that you might need, so feel free to ask.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken @SQLDelete want native SQL statement so naming strategy should have no effect...
I find more strange that the table name got uppercased...

Comment: @Zeromus Please format this as an answer, you were first, and thus deserve bounty reward (if you would, please propose a sugestion compliant with Java/Hibernate standard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@SQLDelete` annotation allows you to define a custom, native SQL query to replace the default hibernate delete.

You should just use Db table and column name as naming strategy won't be used for native sql.